# Automate user input for Batch file

Tags: batch-file, autocomplete, cmd, automation

I am looking to have a batch file login to a database for me and the execute 4 commands.

So here is what I have so far...

```
@echo off 
Echo "password" | config -c && 13 && 14 && 3
pause 
exit
```

So what I need this to do is to automatically accept my password as the first user input, the 13 as the second, the 15 as the third, and the 3 as the forth.
Any advice or input is appreciated.

Comment: Which database engine are you using? SQL Server and MySQL already have command line tools which can do just what you want.

Comment: I am entering this command into a Lawson interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what is right syntax for your `config` command and whether accepts [piped input](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) or not, but

- `Echo "password" | config` redirects to your `config` command all the string `"password"` including double quotes and trailing space (yes, that space before `|`); use `Echo(password|config` instead (no, `echo(` with opening parenthesis is not a keying mistake).
- In the link thereinbefore, note `&&` (doubled ampersand) meaning and check thoroughly `config -c && 13 && 14 && 3` command in that point of view.
- Read [how-to escape characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) (and particularly *Escaping the pipeline* paragraph).

HTH